# Python, Finding Peak width and Peak width at Half Height

Tags: python

Hello Im super new and on a tight deadline so sorry if this question has already been asked.

But I am looking to calculate the width of a peak at total height and half height for a fourier spectral peak.[image: This is a simple peak im looking to analys]

[image: And this is a more complex peak that needs to be analysed]

I don't know if this helps but im using the fft() function in side numpy.

Bye for now and thank you for your help.

Comment: The tight deadline is your responsibility!

Comment: haha, yes yes it is thank you for your input. Very enlightening :P